# How do I correctly execute an Excel VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

My colleagues and I have created a userform with a suite of tools for doing tasks in Excel and Word

I'm quite familiar with spawning application objects from modules and closing them without effecting anything else - or other running copies of Excel.

However the user form must start some where - this leaves an Excel sheet open in the background.

I have tried `Application.Visible = False` but this hides all open workbooks - Kind of annoying if you have other worksheets open

I was thinking of a wrapper sheet which creates an Excel and runs the macro (spawning the macro in its own instance of Excel) - this works but then Im left with the wrapper sheet and potentially an orphan excel app if I close my parent.

Is there a better way than this to execute macros without affecting the rest of the user experience on MS office?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create an Excel add-in. Simply save the Workbook containing your code as an Excel add-in (select the appropriate file format in the "Save As" dialog) and configure Excel to load the add-in at startup in the "Options". You won't see anything of the add-in besides the functionality it provides.

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I was looking for - spawning new copies of excel just felt wrong - Thank you

Comment: Really? Having read your question again, I wasn't sure anymore that this is what you are looking for.